# How to avoid command window popping on cmd.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, windows-installer

I have a command as:

```
cmd.exe /c ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 && echo second command goes here
```

But when executed it opens a command window. Is there a way to avoid the command window from popping up?

PS: I cannot remove cmd.exe from there. As you can see, I am trying to tie two commands one after the other in the same string.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Sorry. Its not a bat file. I want to execute 2 commands in the "UninstallString" of msiexec. I was trying so many things that my question got a bit carried away.

The command is:

```
msiexec <product> <package> && reg delete /xxx
```

Comment: Clearly you can remove cmd.exe. Instead of placing restrictions on potential answers, I suggest you remove such restrictions.

Comment: Batch files always open console windows. If this is a problem, you could consider using VBScript instead. Further reading here: [How do I create a Windows Batch file that does not show the Command Prompt when executed?](http://superuser.com/q/233348)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest option is to start the thing minimized. Shortcut Target:

```
cmd /c START /MIN \path\to\test.bat
```

or

```
cmd /c START /MIN cmd /k ( ping 1.1.1.1 -w 10000 -n 1 && @ECHO All OK)
```

It's not hidden or anything, but it doesn't show up on the desktop or—worse—steal the focus.

If you want the window to go away on its own, "cmd /c ..." will make that happen. "cmd /k ..." will leave the window open.

Plan B is referred to by @CodyGray in the SU link he posted. There are programs that don't open windows, like wperl, pythonw, or wscript (natively available on Windows). If you can pass your command through to one of those things, then you could effectively double-click an icon and have it run "silently."

If Perl's available, I'd certainly go with that because you can craft some pretty powerful one-liners that won't require creating other files.

```
wperl -MWin32 -MNet::Ping -e "$p=Net::Ping->new('icmp',10000); if ($p->ping('192.168.1.1')) { Win32::MsgBox('Ping Successful', 1 + MB_OK, 'All Good'); }"
```

In your example, you're chaining commands together, the latter is a notification. If you don't want to have a window open for the first command, it would be awkward to do it for the second when you're notifying the user of something. Having the process call "cmd /c start cmd /c @echo Everything's OK" would probably do it, but using CMD windows for user notification is probably not something the HCI guys would smile at.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to execute two commands in the "one line" offered by msiexec to uninstall a patch (second command being registry cleanup)

Comment: Thanks.cmd /c START /MIN cmd /c <command1> && <command2> did it. Chaining of the commands was important. I want to put multiple commands in one string provided by MS for msiexec uninstallstring. echo was just an example command (a wrong one) I picked for the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, all batch files open in command-line windows; this has nothing to do with the presence of `cmd.exe` in your particular file. A batch file is simply a number of command-line commands, one per line.

I don't understand why you write `test.bat` the way you do. I'd rather expect

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000
echo second command goes here
```

If, for some bizzare reason, you really need to use only a single line, you can simply do

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 && echo second command goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Andreas Rejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244625/179715) already explained, the command prompt window is not from the explicit `cmd.exe` invocation within your script but from executing the `.bat` script itself. (And despite your claim, you haven't provided any evidence why explicitly invoking `cmd.exe` is necessary.  The whole point of a `.bat` script is to *batch* commands together.)

That said, the [silentbatch](http://www.taenarum.com/software/#win32) program that Paul Miner and I wrote can execute batch scripts and suppress the command prompt window.  To use it, you would have to create a Windows shortcut that invokes `silentbatch.exe test.bat` and double-click on that rather than double-clicking on `test.bat` directly, however.

Comment: How does the linked program work? Does it wait for a console window to show up and then close it?

Comment: @CodyGray It calls `CreateProcess` on the script but sets `STARTUPINFOW::wShowWindow` to `SW_HIDE` (and it optionally redirects stdout and stderr to a log file).  The source code is included with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a shortcut to you batch script and then in the properties select to start the app minimized. It is explained here: [CNET: How to automatically start a program minimized in Windows](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-automatically-start-a-program-minimized-in-windows/)

Step 1: Right-click on the shortcut of the program you want to start minimized and select Properties.
Step 2: Click on the drop-down menu under Run.
Step 3: Select "Minimized," then click the OK button.

Comment: While putting a link is fine, what people also usually do is copy the relevant points inside the answer. This is because the link might break sometime in the future and leave the answer worthless.

Answer (score 0):

From win cmd:

```
start /b cmd.exe /c "ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 & echo second command goes here"
```

runs both commands without opening another cmd window, leaving parent window unblocked for further commands without waiting.