# Multiple commands in UninstallString when removing an app

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, uninstallation

I'm trying to create a homemade installer that replicates the functionality of an MSI. I'm running into trouble setting the [registry values](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/src/Squirrel/UpdateManager.InstallHelpers.cs#L67-L102) for my app, specifically the `UninstallString`, which is supposed to run when you right-click a program and click **Uninstall**. This was my initial `UninstallString`:

```
regedit C:\path\to\app\uninstall.reg & rd /s /q C:\path\to\app
```

For some reason, the `&` was not interpreted correctly and it was passed as an argument to regedit, so I tried this

```
cmd /c "regedit C:\path\to\app\uninstall.reg & rd /s /q C:\path\to\app"
```

This worked fine, but it showed the console window while uninstalling. Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257920/4077294), I tried

```
start /min "..."
```

and

```
start /min cmd /c "..."
```

but they both resulted in an error from the Control Panel, saying the program "was already uninstalled." I also tried it the other way around:

```
cmd /c start /min "..."
```

But the black window still popped up.

Is it possible to make this work without having to show the console window?

Comment: try to add arguments in quotes like `regedit "C:\path\to\app\uninstall.reg" & rd /s /q "C:\path\to\app"`

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
cmd /c start /min cmd /c "..."
```

Gotta love Windows.

Comment: That's because `start` isn't a standalone executable but an internal command of `cmd`. BTW I think you can make a vbscript uninstaller wrapper that won't show any console windows  by using [`shell.run "cmd /c regedit ... & rd ...", 0`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13142667/3959875) (also [autoelevation](http://superuser.com/a/764415/409372) might be a good thing)